# Matlab event listener for network simulator

Tags: matlab, oop, events, listener

I am trying to build a network simulator using object-oriented MatLab. The network simulator is intended to be useful for ad hoc networks, where the topology of the network is unknown beforehand. So, each *Node* in the *Network* has a position in the *Field* (note the use of italics to denote classes or instances) and a transmission radius.

My problem comes with message transmission and reception. I thought of the following approach: whenever a *Node* sends a *Message* it notifies the *Network* about this with a 'MsgSent' event. To handle these events, the *Network* registers a MsgListener for each *Node*. Upon the reception of a 'MsgSent' event, a handleMsgSent() method should be triggered. In this method, the *Network* finds out which *Node*(s) are in range of the sender and call the receive() for each of them.

Next I show some snippets of my classes to illustrate this:

```
classdef Network
    properties
        Nodes       % A list of the Nodes
        Field       % The field associated to the network
    end
    properties (Transient)
         MsgListeners     % List of MsgListeners (1 per node)
    end

    methods
        function net = Network(nnodes, field)
             % Deploys nnodes in the field
             % ....
             for i=1:nnodes
                 net.Nodes = [net.Nodes Node(i, randpos(i,:))];
                 net.MsgListener = [net.MsgListener addlistener(net.Nodes(i), 'MsgSent', @handleMsgSent)];
             end
             % ....
        end

        function handleMsgSent(this, src, msg)
             % Find out the neighbours in range of src and send them the msg
             % ...
             for i=NeighInRange
                 NeighInRange(i).receive(msg)
             end
             % ...
        end
        % ...
    end
end


classdef Node < handle
    properties 
        id              % Node identifier
        pos             % Geographic position [x, y]
        radius  = 0.2   % Transmission radius (default 0.2)
    end

    events
        MsgSent         % Indicates the node has sent a message
    end

    %...
    function send(this, dest, data)
         notify(this, 'MsgSent', Message(this.id, dest, data));
    end        

    function data = receive(this, msg)
         %Check if msg is addressed to this node and do whatever...
    end
    %...
end
```

The point here is I don't seem to be receiving the 'MsgSent' event on the *Network* object and I am not sure whether my approach is correct or should I solve this sending and receiving in a different way.

Any suggestions are extremely appreciated :)

Comment: Two recommendations 1) don't use Matlab oop for a simulation, it is very slow 2) use a discrete event simulation.

Comment: I just want to build my own simple simulator for basic stuff. I used to have my discrete event simulation setup in matlab but it is difficult to maintain, that's why I turned to oop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `handleMsgSent` is a class method, you need to specify on which object it needs to be called:

```
 addlistener(net.Nodes(i), 'MsgSent', @net.handleMsgSent)
```

This is also documented in the [MATLAB documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listener-callback-functions.html#brc8nnr).

The following works for me:

**Network.m**

```
    classdef Network
    properties
        Nodes
    end
    properties (Transient)
         MsgListeners
    end

    methods
        function net = Network(nnodes)
             for i=1:nnodes
                 net.Nodes = [net.Nodes Node(i)];
             end
             for i=1:nnodes 
                net.MsgListeners = [net.MsgListeners addlistener(net.Nodes(i), 'MsgSent', @net.handleMsgSent)];
             end
        end

        function handleMsgSent(this, src, msg)
             for i=1:size(this.Nodes,2)
                 if(this.Nodes(i).id == msg.receiver)
                    this.Nodes(i).receive(msg);
                 end
             end
        end
    end
end
```

**Node.m**

```
classdef Node < handle
    properties
        id
    end

    events
        MsgSent
    end
    methods
        function this = Node(i)
            this.id = i;
        end
        function send(this, dest, data)
            notify(this, 'MsgSent', Message(this.id, dest, data));
        end

        function data = receive(this, msg)
            disp(msg);
        end
    end
end
```

**Message.m**

```
classdef (ConstructOnLoad) Message < event.EventData
    properties
        sender
        receiver
        data  
    end

    methods
       function msg = Message(s, r, d)
             msg.sender = s;
             msg.receiver = r;
             msg.data = d;
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: You are right, but that didn't solved the problem. After I send a message from a node, the handleMsgSent() method is not triggered :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @rutex I updated my answer with a minimal but working version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit. I copied this files into my workspace but for some reason I don't see the message displayed (i.e., disp(msg) at receive()). Any idea why this is happening? I am using Matlab 7.12.0 (R2011a) on Mac OS 10.7.5.

Comment: @rutex: did you clear all objects or restarted Matlab? As long as one instance exists a class definition is not updated.

Comment: @Daniel I created a new folder to contain the files. Then cleared all the workspace (>>clear) and created a new Network (>>net = Network(10)). After that I sent message 'hello' from node 1 to node 2 (>>net.Node(1).send(2,'hello')) but nothing is being prompted after that....

Comment: @rutex It worked for me in R2015a. do you get any warnings? use breakpoints to see which functions are called at all

Comment: @m.s. I did restarted Matlab just in case the clearing was not working, but still the same thing...nothing is prompted. Thanks for the heads up on breakpoints I forgot about that!

Comment: @m.s. your program was entering the handleMsgSent() method but was not printing a thing because of the if clause. I was trying to send a message from node 1 to node 2 but the if was invoking receive() only if the sender was the same as the receiver. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @rutex you are right, I fixed that in my code above